# Debug Ionic 3 code on the device

Tags: android, debugging, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools

I am testing Ionic 3, so far everything works as it should. I would wish to debug the TS code on the ionic lab so i added the next configuration in package.json:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_source_map": "source-map"
}
```

After this, i was able to see the code and debug it(in chrome devTools), but when i execute the same test on the phone i am not able to see the .Ts files and debug it. Anyone has any idea which configuration or how to make them also visible on the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced with this problem, but solution is simple :)
Run command:

```
ionic cordova emulate android -l --debug
```

> - **-l**  Spin up server to live-reload www files
>
>   **--debug** Mark as a debug build

So, when inspecting device/virtual device with `chrome://inspect`, you can debug typescript files, set breakpoints etc as in web app.

> Debugging:
>
> - In Chrome, go to chrome://inspect in the URL bar.
> - Click inspect in your app’s WebView on your device.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Chrome Inspector](https://docs.ionic.io/tools/developer/#prerequisites) to debug Ionic app from the phone.

Prerequisites:

- For Windows, install the necessary USB drivers.
- A USB cable to connect your device.
- Chrome for Android installed and running on your device.
- USB debugging enabled on your device.

Debugging:

- In Chrome, go to chrome://inspect in the URL bar.
- Click inspect in your app’s WebView on your device.

[image]

Comment: Yes i was aware of that, but inside how can you for example debug the .TS code? that i was aware but i couldnt see the .TS code, just some .JS after converted its the only way i do have? cause that generated file has maybe 100k lines and i wonder if for example camera plugins handle or are debugged

Comment: Check this http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20161122-DebuggingIonic2AppsInChromeFromVisualStudioCode.html